# Identify which ViewController got popped

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

I have a mainViewController containing a tableView and each cell pushes a specific customViewController. When it gets popped I want to trigger different function. So my question is how to I identify the viewController that got popped after it got popped.
The first log reads
`lastObject = Optional(<Project.ViewController: 0x61900009c480>)` but in general the idea does not work. Cannot find anything similar on the web. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
print("lastObject = \(String(describing: (self.navigationController?.viewControllers.last)))")

if ((navigationController?.viewControllers.last?.isKind(of:WebViewController.self)) == true){
        print("last is web")
    
    
    }else{
print("is not web")
}
```

Comment: You could use a Custom UINavigationController and override its popping methods.

Comment: @Larme thanks for the recommendation. Currently im doing a "cheap" and fast method of storing a UserDefault value in each viewDidAppear of each Controller but there has to be a better way..

Comment: @snksnk: that's what I've recommended as well. Great that you did already!

Comment: Here is the one simple solution if I understand your question properly, First create one var in main table vc for cell index. This var is keep tracking index of cell which is pushed. Like when you push your custom vc set index within main vc. Now when you popped, in viewDidAppere check index and do your stuff according them.

Comment: @Harish: Yup, i figured thats the easiest shortcut. Im upvoting your answer and thanking you for your time to write an answer, but I'm leaving it open for for any other possible solutions.

Comment: @RajaKishan tried it on the viewWillDisappear but for some reason could not pass the data

Answer (score 1):

Only way is you could subclass the `UINavigationController` and override - `popViewControllerAnimated`. I haven't tried this yet, but possibly a solution.

***Maybe not a best solution but for an temp solution:***
If you have have very less cell in the `UITableView` then you could save the `ViewController` name in `UserDefaults` when the viewController is popped and validate the name in the `viewDidAppear` of mainViewController

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   if (UserDefaultsValue == "FirsViewController"){
     print("last is FirsViewController")
   } else if(UserDefaultsValue == "SecondViewController") {
     print("last is SecondViewController")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one protocol for all controllers something like this

```
protocol WhichPoppedDelegate: class {
func controllerDidPopped(controller: UIViewController)
}
```

assign delegates for each in mainContorller and just call that protocol before you call

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```